# Match and extract values for subset of dataframe

Tags: r, match

I am trying to replace certain values in one dataframe based on a match with another dataframe.

```
df1 <- data.frame("round" = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
              'geocode' = c('AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC'),
              'value1' = c(111, 222, 333, NA, NA, NA, 777, 888, 999))

df2 <- data.frame('geocode' = c('AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC'), 'value2' = c(444, 555, 666))
```

Desired output:

```
out.df <- data.frame("round" = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
                 'geocode' = c('AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC'),
                 'value1' = c(111, 222, 333, 444, 555, 666, 777, 888, 999))
```

My attempted solution:

```
df1[df1$round == 2, 'value1'] <- df2$value2[match(df1$geocode, df2$geocode)]
```

I can't seem to get around the fact that the two dataframes have different number of rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You lost a condition

```
df1[df1$round == 2, 'value1'] <- df2$value2[match(df1[df1$round == 2, 'geocode'], df2$geocode)]
```

Comment: Thanks, knew I needed something like that but couldn't get it precisely. Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you only want to replace the NA in your `df1$value1`. In that case, you need to specify this condition, i.e.

```
df1$value1[is.na(df1$value1)] <- df2$value2[match(df1$geocode, df2$geocode)][is.na(df1$value1)]
```

Comment: Thanks, I used NA in the dummy df and thus this solution also works. In actual df there are non-NA values; will be more careful next time.

Answer (score 0):

how about this?

```
library(plyr)
df=join(df1,df2,by="geocode",type="left")
df[is.na(df$value1),]$value1=df[is.na(df$value1),]$value2
```

Comment: you are right it is from plyr package, I added the library in the code

Comment: Why not simply use `merge` rather than loading a package just to join?